# Pictures is put behind text

Tags: positioning, wrapfigure

I have an weird problem then I insert an picture like this:

```
\begin{wrapfigure}{R}{7cm}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{./pictures/DBuserTabel.png}%{./Pictures/mainscreen1.png}
  \caption{Uklip af User tablen i Databasen}
  \label{fig:databaseUserTable}
\end{wrapfigure}
```

It looks like this:
[image]

And its the completely different place. This picture should be at the bottom of the page.

[Here is the main document](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/2230967/The%20SOMA%20Project.tex) and [here is the database file that the problem](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/2230967/database.tex).

Comment: The code snippet won't do... You should post a full [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) so we can trace the problem.

Comment: If you want to put the picture on bottom of the page use `{figure}[b]` not `wrapfigure` which is for wrapping text around the image.

Comment: Only the position of the picture is suppose to be at the botton. Still wrap around the text.

Comment: But the weird thing is that it's only in this chapter. Im doing the same thing other places.

Comment: the `wrapfig` documentation clearly states that figures must be placed either at the left or the right (which may also be expressed as "inside" or "outside").  you are trying to center a figure, and that just won't work.

Comment: Have you tried to change the positioning from `R` to `r`? Capitals makes the image to float.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: I think `\centering` is used inside the bounding box here, hence I don't think that is the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two things one should remember while using the `wrapfigure`.

1. The page breaks should be taken care of *manually*.
2. The correct placement options `{R}` or `{r}` should be used.

In your case, the figure comes at the end of a page and you are allowing latex to float it  (by using `{R}`). That is why the figure goes to the top. When we change it to `{r}` (means *exactly here*) we get,

```
  ........
  til samme server/data. En anden grund var også at vi ikke har brugt MySQL ret meget hvilket vi begge gerne ville, for at lære at bruge det. Dog var det ikke noget specielt krav.

\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{10cm}
 \centering
\includegraphics[width=9cm]{example-image-a}%{./pictures/planning}
\caption{Complet Soma Database}
\label{fig:databaseComplet}
\end{wrapfigure}

\section{Database opbygning.}\label{sec:databaseopbygning}

Databasens opbygning har ændret sig meget fra start til slut. Fra start af var databasen
..........
```

[image]

Now the worry is about page break. We place the

```
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{10cm}
 \centering
\includegraphics[width=9cm]{example-image-a}%{./pictures/planning}
\caption{Complet Soma Database}
\label{fig:databaseComplet}
\end{wrapfigure}
```

inside the section `\section{Database opbygning.}\label{sec:databaseopbygning}` like:

```
.....
\section{Database opbygning.}\label{sec:databaseopbygning}
%
Databasens opbygning har ændret sig meget fra start til slut. Fra start af var databasen meget stor, og en smule indviklet at overskue. Men  efter flere omstruktureringer blev databasen, mere simplere og mere overskuelig og derved også nemmere at arbejde videre på, men også mere effektiv. Grunden til der er lavet 2 databaser til brugere. Er at den ene database som indholder login oplysninger, på senere tidspunkt skal kunne bruges til flere systemer og ikke kun The Soma Project. Vi har så valgt at når du opretter en bruger i databasen, er der en trigger på User tabellen som automatisk går ind op opretter brugeren
%
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{10cm}
 \centering
\includegraphics[width=9cm]{example-image-a}%{./pictures/planning}
\caption{Complet Soma Database}
\label{fig:databaseComplet}
\end{wrapfigure}
% 
i login databasen, så man derved kun skal oprette brugen et sted og triggeren så tager sig af resten. \newline
Grunden til vi prøver at holde designet simpelt er både pga. at den er nemmere at overskue og
.......
```

we get:

[image]

which is the desired placement.

**Conclsions and notes**

1. When you use `wrapfigure`, generally you don't mean it to float.
   Hence, use smaller case placement holders like `r` and `l`....
2. The code should be placed at appropriate place in your .tex file so that it takes care of the page breaks (you should do it manually).
3. What we need here is the Minimum (non)Working Example. We don't expect you to put your entire code given as a link. Please try to reduce your code to the minimum and try to post it here in this site. Now your code had graphics and other `\incude...` files which we could not compile. If a MWE is given here, it will be easy for those who try to help you out of the problem.